# how to solve 403 forbidden error while using svn commit first time

Tags: iphone, svn, xcode

hellow all i am using svn for version control for an iphone application . 
 i have created it from xcode repositories by giving url ,user name and password 
its authenticated .After that i have created a directory from there itself and have imported my project there. Then i have checked out to the local directory and have updated something in it. Click on commit changes. It done. After that i came to terminal to commit the project  first time from terminal .There i have removed the build of the project then gave  a command like "svn update".
here i am getting error like

svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/pacman/GameDevelopment/Game'and 403 Forbidden error
whts going wrong here?
could any one help me in this ?
If there is a problem in server settings..How could i set it
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether you can connect to your SVN repo from command line.

Looks like you don't have access to the SVN repo (403 forbidden)

EDIT:

Actually, it looks like you tried it from the command line already. See what the output of:

```
svn ls <your SVN repo URL>
```

If it's still giving you `403 Forbidden`, then you might want to check your SVN server setting.

Comment: oh thanks for your quick response .yes the same error is coming again.. so what can i do now i mean when i configure the repo from xcode its get connected  and it shows it is authenticated also . Thanks

Comment: If you are still having the `403 Forbidden` error while doing `svn ls`, then you might want to check with your server admin (or whoever is setting up the SVN server). How do you connect to your SVN repo? What protocol are you using? I suggest that you try to fix the problem from *outside* xcode first.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment.  Xcode is _really_ poor at reporting subversion problems.  I would check on the command line first.

Comment: i connected it from xcode  and configured. the protocal is https .how to fix that from out side i mean could you give the flow .i dnt have idea thanks

Comment: As I said in the original answer, did you try the `svn ls` command from the *command line*? What output did it displays? Xcode's SVN problem reporting is very poor, as said by Daniel above. Maybe the problem is with your SVN server configuration.

Comment: yes I have tried with svn ls  command from command line.the same error of "403 forbidden" error is coming .svn server configuration is correct only.Because when i am connecting through xcode after giving password it given that authenicated.